# How to access the id of the selected row in Yii Cgridview through double click?

Tags: yii

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'message-grid',
    //'selectionChanged'=>'js:function(id){location.href = "'.$this->createUrl('view').'/id/"+$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);}', 
    'selectionChanged'=>'function(id){location.href = "'.$this->createUrl('view').'&id="+$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id)+"&f=s";}',
//'dataProvider'=>$model->sentitem(),
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),    
'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
            array(      
                        'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
                        'id'=>'chk',
                        'selectableRows'=>'2',
                        //'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'40px'),

            ),
```

),
));

> I already wrote the code for single click through selection changed I am trying to access the id through jquery dbclick function, I don't know how to fetch the id using selection changed in dbclick

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#message-grid tbody tr').live('dbclick', function() {
    var id = $.fn.yiiGridView.getKey(
        'message-grid',
        $(this).prevAll().length 
    );
});
```

Comment: Any errors? Try to console.log `id` in dbclick handler, what does it return?

Comment: Note, that `$.fn.yiiGridView.getKey` is marked as **deprecated** as of `Yii 1.1.9`.

Answer (score 0):

the folowing code will load the view page of the item. 
( url => itemcontroller/view/id/+selectedId )

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'id-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'filter'=>$model,

    'selectableRows'=>1,
    'selectionChanged'=>'function(id){ location.href = "'.$this->createUrl('view').'/id/"+$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);}',
```